# Create new records in Salesforce1 app

Tags: salesforce1-app, create-records

So I'm playing around with the Salesforce1 app on an iPad.  Maybe I'm missing something, but I can't seem to create new records, either at the top level (like Account) or a child record (like Contact).  I don’t seem to see the buttons/links for doing that.  Can someone advise me on this?

Thx,
Hamayoun

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You create them via Chatter Publisher Actions - make sure Enable Publisher Actions is checked in Chatter Settings, and then that the actions you want (e.g. New Account) is added to the Global Publisher Layout under the Chatter Settings.

If so, you should see the new option when you click the + button on the bottom right of the screen (it can take a little while to appear on the app, but if you go to one/one.app you should see it immediately)

Comment: So I have to create an explicit publisher action for every object I want users to be able to create?

Comment: I believe so - they are tied to an object. BUt the main CRM objects already have pre-defined ones